# How to read/write file to HDFS use php on the web

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How could i write word on the web, and save the content to a file, and the file write to hdfs.
It's use the php write the content to a file, and move the file to hdfs file path? Or use thrift? Please give me a clue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [webhdfs](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r2.0.0-alpha/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/index.html), which provides a REST interface to HDFS.

Comment: It's use curl to read/write? So how could i implements, i should setting on the hadoop? Thx

Comment: Well, any mechanism of generating HTTP requests and parsing HTTP responses will work, so you could use PHP, rather than curl.

To set up the server, see http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r2.0.0-alpha/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/ServerSetup.html.

Comment: Hello 

try once HDFS library from hadoop in PHP: https://github.com/simpleenergy/php-WebHDFS